# pass a method as a parameter in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have the method `send` below, the method pass a method `eventService.send(request)` as parameter.
I don't like it to be written as is, since the  `eventService.send(request)` is the main functionality in the code. 
I am wondering is there an inelegant way to pass the method as parameter or the other option is to extract it to an object :

One option :

```
     public Response send(EventServiceRequest request){
       ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> responseEntity;

       responseEntity = handleResponse(eventService.send(request),request);
     return Response.status(responseEntity.getStatusCode().value()).entity(responseEntity.getBody()).build();
     }
```

Second option :

```
     public Response send(EventServiceRequest request){
       ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> responseEntity;
       EventServiceResponse resp = eventService.send(request);
       responseEntity = handleResponse(resp,request);
     return Response.status(responseEntity.getStatusCode().value()).entity(responseEntity.getBody()).build();
     }
```

```
     private ResponseEntity<EventServiceResponse> handleResponse(EventServiceResponse response, EventServiceRequest request) {
        return handleResponse(response, request, null, null);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example by following this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can only use lambda's to pass logic to methods if they expect a functional interface. A functional interface in this case is an interface with a single abstract method (SAM).

Out of the box, java 8 offers a few of these interfaces, like `Function<T, R>`. This is a method that converts something of type T into something of type R.

As an example, it can be defined as follows:

```
    public void printFunctionResult(Function<String, String> function)
    {
        System.out.println(function.apply("input"));
    }
```

And then used in this way:

```
    printFunctionResult(string -> "passed: " + string);
```

In this case, it would print `passed: input`